# Replace all occurrences matching given patterns

Tags: java, regex

Having following string:

`String value = "/cds/horse/schema1.0.0/day=12321/provider=samsung/run_key=32ee/group_key=222/end_date=2020-04-20/run_key_default=32sas1/somethingElse=else"`

In need to replace values of `run_key` and `run_key_default` with `%`, for example, for above string result output will be the:

`"/cds/horse/schema1.0.0/day=12321/provider=samsung/run_key=%/group_key=222/end_date=2020-04-20/run_key_default=%/somethingElse=else"`

I would like to avoid mistakenly modifying other values, so in my opinion the best solution for it is combining `replaceAll` method with `regex`

`String output = value.replaceAll("\run_key=[*]\", "%").replaceAll("\run_key_default=[*]\", "%")`

I'm not sure how should I construct regex for it?

Feel free to post if you know better solution for it, than this one which I provided.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may use this regex for search:

```
(/run_key(?:_default)?=)[^/]*
```

and for replacement use:

```
"$1%"
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/cSyN90/1)

**Java Code:**

```
String output = value.replaceAll("(/run_key(?:_default)?=)[^/]*", "$1%");
```

**RegEx Details:**

- `(`: Start capture group #1

  - `/run_key`: Match literal text `/run_key`
  - `(?:_default)?`: Match `_default` *optionally*
  - `=`: Match a literal `=`
- `)`: End capture group #1
- `[^/]*`: Match 0 or more of any characters that is not `/`
- `"$1%"` is **replacement** that puts our 1st capture group back followed by a literal `%`

Comment: Thank you master :)

Answer (score 1):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        final String regex = "(run_key_default|run_key)=\\w*"; //regex
        final String string = "/cds/horse/schema1.0.0/day=12321/provider=samsung/run_key=32ee/group_key=222/end_date=2020-04-20/run_key_default=32sas1/somethingElse=else";
        final String subst = "$1=%"; //group1 as it is while remaining part with % 

        final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
        final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);

        final String result = matcher.replaceAll(subst);

        System.out.println("Substitution result: " + result);
    }
```

output

Substitution result:

```
/cds/horse/schema1.0.0/day=12321/provider=samsung/run_key=%/group_key=222/end_date=2020-04-20/run_key_default=%/somethingElse=else
```